# Visual C++ for Linux Development + Docker

Tags: linux, visual-studio, ubuntu, docker, gdb

I would like to develop a Linux C++ app by building and debugging in a Docker container. I intend to use [Visual C++ for Linux Development](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/725025cf-7067-45c2-8d01-1e0fd359ae6e) to remote debug into the container. However this Visual Studio extension was originally intended for use with a Linux VM, Linux development and Docker are new to me, and I'm a little stuck on the basics of setting it up.

I have created an `ubuntu:14.04` docker container and I have installed the Visual C++ for Linux dependencies in the container, namely `openssh-server`, `g++`, `gdb` and `gdbserver`. I have committed the container, creating an image to work with. I think I now need to run the container opening up a port so that I can connect to the container from Visual Studio.

How is this done? Does the container need to be further set up so that there is some kind of handler to handle communication on the port which is going to be opened? For instance does `Bash` need to be assigned to handle communication over the port? Or does one of the dependencies, perhaps `openssh-server`, need to be assigned to handle communication over the port? Or was something set up when I installed the dependencies? If so on which port?

In the Visual C++ for Linux Development instructions it shows that credentials such as `Host name`, `Port`, `User name`, `Authentication type`, and `Password` can be provided when connecting to a VM. Naturally Port will be required but will the others be required? If so do these credentials need to be set in the Ubuntu container or discovered somehow? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this docker image [ducatel/visual-studio-linux-build-box](https://hub.docker.com/r/ducatel/visual-studio-linux-build-box/) with a VM (like in the readme) or with docker for windows